# Xcopy Command excluding files and folders

Tags: command-line, cmd, xcopy

I want to copy files and folders in a directory to another folder excluding a list of files and folders.Is that possible.

I was just trying to copy excluding file :

```
 xcopy c:\t1 c:\t2 /EXCLUDE:exclusion.txt
```

But it keeps saying read cant read file : exclusion.txt

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: try `copy /?` and read the portion titled `/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just give full path to exclusion file: eg..

-- **no** - - - - -`xcopy c:\t1 c:\t2 /EXCLUDE:list-of-excluded-files.txt`

**correct** - - - `xcopy c:\t1 c:\t2 /EXCLUDE:C:\list-of-excluded-files.txt`

In this example the file would be located ***" C:\list-of-excluded-files.txt "***

or...

**correct** - - - `xcopy c:\t1 c:\t2 /EXCLUDE:C:\mybatch\list-of-excluded-files.txt`

In this example the file would be located ***" C:\mybatch\list-of-excluded-files.txt "***

Full path fixes syntax error.

Answer (score 18):

Like Andrew said `/exclude` parameter of xcopy should be existing file that has list of excludes.

Documentation of [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx) says:

> Using /exclude
>
> List each string in a separate line in each file. If any of the listed
>   strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be copied,
>   that file is then excluded from the copying process. For example, if
>   you specify the string "\Obj\", you exclude all files underneath the
>   Obj directory. If you specify the string ".obj", you exclude all files
>   with the .obj extension.

Example:

```
xcopy c:\t1 c:\t2 /EXCLUDE:list-of-excluded-files.txt
```

and `list-of-excluded-files.txt` should exist in current folder (otherwise pass full path), with listing of files/folders to exclude - one file/folder per line. In your case that would be:

```
exclusion.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

It is same as above answers, but is simple in steps

c:\SRC\folder1

c:\SRC\folder2

c:\SRC\folder3

c:\SRC\folder4

to copy all above folders to c:\DST\  except folder1 and folder2.

Step1:
create a file c:\list.txt with below content, one folder name per one line

folder1\

folder2\

Step2:
Go to command pompt and run as below
xcopy c:\SRC*.*  c:\DST*.* /EXCLUDE:c:\list.txt