# How to differentiate between system and user files in the batch language?

Tags: file, batch-file, computer-science

I am looking to copy all text files on the C drive, but the program needs to avoid text files that are part of the system, and only copy the text files that have been created by the user.

Is there a built in way to do this, or do I need to get creative? If so, how would you go about it? I would like to keep it within batch and not involve powershell or anything like that.

I thought about using creation dates to determine whether or not a file is a system file, but that didn't work all the way.

Comment: If you do a dir /q , are all the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM files the system files you are talking about or do they include the ones which are BUILTIN\Administrators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a list of all systemfiles using the `dir` command. So

```
dir /b /as > %USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt
```

Would generate a list of the systemfiles from that directory.

Using xcopy as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21447865/6707985) you can now copy all files from one directory to another excluding the systemfiles.

The xcopy command should be something like this:

```
xcopy C:\firstDirectory\*.txt C:\secondDirectory /EXCLUDE:%USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt
```

#### Edit

So your code that is there would copy all rtf and txt files from the whole C drive to Drive D folder E.

A batch-file using my method would look like this:

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\
dir /b /as /s > %USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt
xcopy C:\*.rtf D:\E /EXCLUDE:%USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt /s
xcopy C:\*.txt D:\E /EXCLUDE:%USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt /s
```

Explanation:
`@echo off` supresses redundant output of the commands that would be displayed before execution.
`cd /d C:\` changes the current execution directory to the root of the C drive. `/d` is added for potential drive change.
`dir /b /as /s > %USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt` redirects the output of the dir command into a file in your userprofile (Usually `C:\Users\yourUserName`). The switch `/b` will only show the filenames and not size, creation date etc. `/as` will only list system files and `/s` makes the dir command work recursively through all directories.
`xcopy C:\*.rtf D:\E /EXCLUDE:%USERPROFILE%\excluded_Files.txt /s` will copy all rtf files from C:\ to D:\E and exclude all files from the list previously created (that will contain all system txt *and* rtf files (as well as others)). `/s` makes xcopy work recursively as for dir.
Next line is a copy of the same with txt files.

Comment: So for the code: `for /R "C:\" %%G in (*.rtf *.txt) do copy "%%G" "D:\E"` how would that work out? Probably a basic question but I'm just learning batch right now.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: Hey, Geister, I just ran the code and I noticed that some System32/SysWOW64 text files are copied, are these not considered system files / are only some files system files in System32?

Comment: I can only use what is given by the help of the commands. Run `dir /?` in a command prompt. It will tell the same as I did. I am no Windows system/file expert at all...